# Largest Bitcoin transaction fee ever paid?

Tags: transaction-fees

What was the largest transaction fee ever paid? Assuming that payment was an accident was the sender able to contact the miner who mined that block and negotiate a full or partial refund?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[This transaction](https://blockchain.info/tx/cc455ae816e6cdafdb58d54e35d4f46d860047458eacf1c7405dc634631c570d) (2016-04-26) has even higher fees (291.2409 BTC).

[This plot](https://twitter.com/random_walker/status/729800710280335361) shows transaction fees higher than 1000USD from the past 3 years. From the plot, the April 2016 transaction seems to be the one paying the highest fee.

[BitClub offered to refund](http://www.coindesk.com/accidental-136000-bitcoin-mining-pool/) the transaction, but the whole episode was a bit [controversial](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1452787.0).

Answer (score 5):

I think this one: http://btc.blockr.io/tx/info/4ed20e0768124bc67dc684d57941be1482ccdaa45dadb64be12afba8c8554537 - 200 BTC fee!

It was an accidental fee scooped up by ASICMiner, but [they refunded the guy](https://www.reddit.com/r/Bitcoin/comments/1lb5my/asicminer_refunds_the_accidental_200_btc/).

Comment: There are honest people in the world. Happy to hear about that huge refund!